# Sqlite update "add data" all Rows without replace

Tags: android, sqlite

How I can add text without replace data ?

usually us, update and change the value, but is there any way to preserve the value + add another?

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(text, newText;
db.update(table, values,....  ", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with db.update(). I can't give you an exact answer, since I don't know what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to keep your database schema as it is, you need to get the existing record, get the existing value from it, append the new value to the existing value, and then update the database with the resulting value.

Answer (score 0):

To apend some text to all values in a column, execute an SQL command like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Text = Text + 'new text'
```

The `update` function does not support SQL expressions; it always replaces values.
The above command must be executed with the [execSQL function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) instead:

```java
db.execSQL("UPDATE "+table+" SET "+text+" = "+text+" + ?",
           new Object[] { newText });
```